# Pragma omp parallel for - more nested for loops

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, openmp, parallel.foreach, pragma

What is the best way to parallel more then two for (nested) loops inside some other for loop? So for examlpe there is four for loops inside another one

```
For{ for{...} for{...}for{...}for{...}}
```

When I have just one for loop inside another I use

```
#pragma omp parallel{.     
  #pragma omp for }
```

And I use nowait when needed, but what is the right solution when there is more then one loop inside?
I need this to parallel code for making spiral matrix.

I have tried so far

```
cnt = 1;
    //#pragma omp parallel
    int layer;
    {
    for ( layer = 0; layer < (n + 1) / 2; layer++) {
        // direction 1 - traverse from left to right
        #pragma ompa parallel for
        for (int ptr = layer; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[layer][ptr] = cnt++;
        }
        // direction 2 - traverse from top to bottom
        #pragma ompa parallel for
        for (int ptr = layer + 1; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[ptr][n - layer - 1] = cnt++;
        }
        // direction 3 - traverse from right to left
        #pragma ompa parallel for
        for (int ptr = n - layer - 2; ptr >= layer; ptr--) {
            result1[n - layer - 1][ptr] = cnt++;
        }
        // direction 4 - traverse from bottom to top
        #pragma ompa parallel for
        for (int ptr = n - layer - 2; ptr > layer; ptr--) {
            result1[ptr][layer] = cnt++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parallel code for printing???? Printing is a typical serial process. More information is needed to answer the question. The number of loop counts? Dependencies? How long does the whole process take? etc. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @Laci my mistake, I will update my question. I need it to generate/ make spiral matrix

Comment: There's no general answer, we need some code example to give a pertinent answer.

Comment: @PierU I have added code example. So far I have tried to parallel all four inside for loops

Comment: Why do you need a parallel code for this? Is it a homework or do you really need a fast code to fill up a matrix? How big is `n` ? Your code has race conditions - when different threads increase `cnt`, so the result will be incorrect. `ompa` should be `omp`

Comment: If your aim is to learn OpenMP you should consider using the `linear` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, necessary conditions for an efficient OpenMP parallelization are

- each thread has a significant amount of work to perform, otherwise the OpenMP overheads rule the runtime
- the "arithmetic intensity" (i.e. the number of operations per input/output byte) is high enough, otherwise the code is "memory bound" (i.e. the bottleneck is the CPU-RAM transfers and little speed-up can be obtained by using more cores)

For the first condition I don't know how big is your `n`. For the second condition for each element of `result` your are performing only 4 assignements and 4 additions, which is a low arithmetic intensity.

Anyway... As mentionned by Laci in the comments there is a race condition on `cnt` between different threads. Proctecting the increment instruction with an atomic clause is not not enough here, as it will be still incremented out of order. So the `linear` clause is the only simple solution.

Also, you don't really need here to define a parallel region that encompasses the 4 loops, and each loop can define its own parallel region:

```
cnt = 1;
    for ( int layer = 0; layer < (n + 1) / 2; layer++) {
        // direction 1 - traverse from left to right
        #pragma omp parallel for linear(cnt:1)
        for (int ptr = layer; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[layer][ptr] = cnt++;
        }
        // direction 2 - traverse from top to bottom
        #pragma omp parallel for linear(cnt:1)
        for (int ptr = layer + 1; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[ptr][n - layer - 1] = cnt++;
        }
        [...]
    }
```

or parallelizing the outer loop as suggested by Laci:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int layer = 0; layer < (n + 1) / 2; layer++) {

        int cnt = 1 + 4*layer*(n-layer); // TO BE CHECKED!

        // direction 1 - traverse from left to right
        for (int ptr = layer; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[layer][ptr] = cnt++;
        }
        // direction 2 - traverse from top to bottom
        for (int ptr = layer + 1; ptr < n - layer; ptr++) {
            result1[ptr][n - layer - 1] = cnt++;
        }
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: 1) you should use `cnt++`, 2) you can obtain a faster code by parallelizing the outermost loop and calculate the initial `cnt` for a given layer as a function of `layer` and `n`.

Comment: @Laci corrected and added

Comment: On my computer (using dynamic schedule) the first parallel code a bit slower, the second code ca. 6x faster than the serial one. https://godbolt.org/z/nxe5zMhqr